# Get css values of a hover element in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, hover

I can get css of an element in an iframe by this way:

```
var bg_color = $('iframe.#myIframe').contents().find('div#someId').css('background-color');
```

but I can't get:

```
var bg_color = $('iframe.#myIframe').contents().find('div#someId:hover').css('background-color');
```

So, how can I get css of a hover element in an iframe (same domain)? Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: You can't, jQuery doesn't have access to pseudo selectors.

Comment: I've edited. Please help me!

Answer (score -1):

This cannot be done, the iFrame is literally a window to another webpage, therefor it is not in your DOM, and not accessible by your jquery

Comment: My iframe is in the same domain with my site. Could it be?